# How to reference the customer account navigation container block which doesn't have a "name" or "as" attribute in Magento 2?

Tags: layout, customer-account, magento2.2

As the title says, how can I reference a layout block which doesn't have a "name" or "as" attrbitue?

Specifically, I'm trying to reference the `Customer Account menu` and add a `title` argument in `customer_account.xml`.

Here's the title argument which I'm trying to add:

```
<argument name="block_title" xsi:type="string">User account</argument>
```

to:

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::html/collapsible.phtml" before="-">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="block_css" xsi:type="string">account-nav</argument>
    </arguments>
    ... more code here ...
</block>
```

Not sure how to go about this, except to edit the vendor `customer_account.xml`. Which is something I'd rather not do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in Magento 2.2.

The customer account navigation container block now has the name `sidebar.main.account_nav` and can be referenced.

```
<referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
     <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="sidebar.main.account_nav" template="Magento_Theme::html/collapsible.phtml" before="-">
     <arguments>
          <argument name="block_css" xsi:type="string">account-nav</argument>
     </arguments>
          <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Navigation" name="customer_account_navigation" before="-">
          ...
```